# Consider the following program written in Java. why this output **2 2**. I think this should be output **1 1**

Tags: java

Consider the following program written in Java. Why is the output **2 2**? I think it should output **1 1**

```java
class Access{
  static int x;
  void increment(){
    x++;
  }
}

public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Access obj1 = new Access();
    Access obj2 = new Access();
    obj1.x = 0;
    obj1.increment();
    obj2.increment();
    System.out.println(obj1.x + " " + obj2.x);
  }
}
```

Comment: `static int x;` - Do you understand how `static` works?

Comment: [Static Variable](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable) Please read it.

Comment: If you had used a good IDE, it would have warned you about `obj1.x` with "The static field Access.x should be accessed in a static way", telling you that something about your code is not as it should be. Please use a good IDE and pay attention to the warnings!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static variables are shared among all the instances of the class, they are useful when we need to do memory management. In some cases we want to have a common value for all the instances like global variable then it is much better to declare them static as this can save memory (because only single copy is created for static variables).

So when obj1.increment() is called it update the value of x by 1. And when obj2.increment() is called it update the same static reference by +1 and makes it 2. at end ypu are getting both the values as 2. Below code snippet will print values as 1 and 2.

```
obj1.increment();
System.out.println(obj1.x);
obj2.increment();
System.out.println(obj2.x);
```